# Остановка/удаление ajax запроса

Tags: jquery, ajax

Как осуществить остановку/удаление запроса ajax запроса в jquery?

Метод abort(); пишет как не существующий. Не нашел нормального решения в google.

Возможно кто-то знает как?

делал примерно так

```
      var ajaxxx = $.ajax(...);

      ajaxxx.abort();
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/jbZTjv3UKjsnMrtLBC9Q?p=preview у вас вероятно древний jQuery

Comment: да нет. 1.9 вроде

Comment: тогда, вы что-то недоговариваете, т.к. в моем примере всё отлично работает.

Comment: @eicto а все причина была в том что я назвал запрос ajax так же как и функцию в которой она была. спасибо